# Сложность с Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Только установил AS, обновил Android SDK, но при сборке даже пустого проекта возникает ошибка, также не находит класс AppCompatActivity. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описаниеображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют

Comment: А вы добавили библитеку `appcompat` в проект? Если вы только начинаете, советую не заморачиваться и поменять `AppCompatActivity` на `Activity`. Вернетесь, когда поймёте принципы

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.2.1'` в блок `dependencies` в файл `build.gradle` уровня модуля.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вероятнее всего не докачали SDK до конца, скачайте всё из вкладок `Tools` и `Extras` в вашем SDK Manager'e.